# Android studio disappearing code

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I opened a project I had done some work on last week and found that the files had been emptied? The android manifest file had been changed to this :

```
       [    W          x
             >   X   r   �   �   �   �   �   �     *  L  n  �  �  �  �  �    *  8  z  �  �  �  $  T  r  �  �  �  �       4  L  ^  ~  �  �  �  �      .  @  T  `  �  �  �  �  �  .  p  �  �  :  �  �  &  r  �  
      Z   �   �   X
  �
  �
  P  �    \  �  
  N
  �
    N  �  �  *  �  �  6  v  �    b  �    h  �  �  2  �  �     j  �  �  D  �  �  *  x  �  >  �  �  N  �     �  �    X  �  �  V  �  �  N  �     X  �    ^  �  �    |  �  D   �   !  �!  �!  B"  �"  �"  J#  �#  $  `$  �$  8%  �%  �%  V&  �&  '  �'  �'  t(  �(  ()  �)  *  �*  +  �+  2,  �,  $-  �-  .  �.   /  �/  0  �0  (1  �1  &2  �2   3  �3  4  �4  �4  25  �5  �5  (6  l6  �6  �6  J7  �7  �7  R8  �8  �8  r9  �9  :  �:  �:  N;  �;  �;  D<  �<  �<   =  j=  �=  >  j>  �>  ?  ^?  �?  �?  <@  �@  �@  A  lA  �A  B  FB  �B  �B  @C  �C   D  `D  �D  �D  DE  �E  �E  6F  �F  �F  XG  �G  H  vH  �H  BI  �I  J  NJ  �J  �J  DK  �K  �K  VL  �L  2M  �M  &N  ~N  �N  (O  rO  �O  P  bP  �P  �P  Q  vQ  �Q  .R  �R  �R  $S  xS  �S  T  |T  �T  U  vU  V  NV  �V  W  vW  �W  X  �X  �X  RY  �Y  �Y  0Z  �Z  �Z  [  V[  �[  �[  4\  �\  �\  B]  �]  L^  �^  
_  n_  �_  P`  �`  Na  �a  :b  �b  c  �c  �c  Pd  �d  �d  e  ^e  �e  f  pf  �f  g  �g  �g  Jh  �h  �h  Vi  �i  j  jj  �j  
k  Vk  �k  l  jl  �l  m  �m  �m  Hn  �n  o  no  �o  p  �p  �p  2q  rq  �q  �q  >r  �r  �r  Js  �s  t  �t  �t  Bu  �u  (v  �v  �v  w  6w  ^w  �w  8x  �x  �x  \y  �y  z  nz  �z  ,{  �{  �{  4|  �|  �|  H}  �}  ~  �~     l  �  �  j�  ��  
�  L�  ��  �  R�  ��  $�  ��  ҃  <�  ��  �  H�  ��  �  F�  ��  ��  T�  ��   �  f�  Ԉ  ��  >�  ��  ȉ  �  R�  ��  Ԋ  �  N�  ��  ҋ  �  d�  ��  ��  R�  ��  �  @�  ��  ʎ  �  `�  ��  �  J�  ��  ؐ  "�  d�  đ  "�  d�  ��  ޒ   �  h�  ��  �  <�  ��  ޔ  2�  n�  ܕ  L�  ��  �  0�  ��  ڗ  �  r�  ̘  �  z�  Ι  "�  x�  Ț  ,�  ��  ��  P�  ��  ֜  ��  J�  ��  ֝  "�  n�  ��  �  r�  ğ  �  `�  ��  �  *�  |�  ��  �  8�  ��  �  H�  ��  ֣  �  `�  ��  ��  4�  t�  ȥ  �  D�  ��  Ц  �  `�  ��  ��  4�  ��  Ҩ  �  ~�  ީ  :�  ��  �  B�  ��  ��  T�  ��  ��  R�  ��  �  h�  ��  �  F�  ��  ̯  �  l�  ��  �  `�  ��  �  Z�  ��  �  6�  ��  γ  *�  ��  �  B�  ��  ֵ  &�  `�  ��  �  T�  ��  
�  Z�  ��  ��  N�  ��  ܹ  ,�  ��  Ժ  $�  n�  ̻  "�  l�  ȼ  "�  l�  ��  �  .�  |�  ��  
�  \�  ��  �  \�  ��  ��  $�  ��  ��  �  R�  ��  ��  .�  ��  ��  (�  f�  ��  ��  L�  ��  ��  &�  x�  ��  .�  z�  ��  *�  n�  ��  �  F�  ��  ��  8�  ��  ��  "�  n�  ��  &�  t�  ��  *�  ��  �  P�  ��  ��  6�  ��  ��  "�  x�  ��  4�  ��  ��  "�  j�  ��  
�  Z�  ��  ��  >�  ��  ��  $�  f�  ��  (�  ��  ��  \�  ��  ��  P�  ��  ��  d�  ��  ��  J�  ��  ��  N�  ��  ��  �  N�  ��  ��  �  t�  ��  �  h�  ��  ��  N�  ��  ��  Z�  ��  ��  j�  ��   �  V�  ��  ��  6�  ��  ��  `�  ��  ��  N�  ��  ��  <�  ��  ��  &�  ��  ��  4�  ��  �  `�  ��  *�  j�  ��  �  l�  ��  �  ��  ��  ,�  v�  ��  �  l�  ��  $�  2�  ��  ��  d�  ��  �  `�  ��  �  d�  ��  "�  ��  ��  R�  ��  ��  $�  v�  ��  �  ��  ��  6�  ��  ��  6�  ��  ��  H�  b�  r�  ��  ��  4�  >�  \�  l�  ��  ��   �  >�  ��  ��  "�  ��  ��  T�  ��  �   �  p�  ��  ��  X�  ��    l  �   x � 8 p �  V � �  v � � � � � ^ � , � � 4 � * � � J     �   �   0
 �
 �
 �
```

Of which is just a small segment!

Does anyone know what could cause this and how I could change it back?

Comment: Source control; save early save often. If you have not done these, then there is no undo operation

Comment: Any idea what could've caused it to happen?

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem, but generally speaking, the file is corrupt. There's a long list of reasons files become corrupted, but it would usually happen at the OS level, not necessarily preventable without remote backups